# How to connect to MongoDB on CloudBees using Spring Data (XML config)?

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, cloudbees, spring-data-mongodb

To learn (spring/mongoBD/CLoudBees), I have created a mongoDB instance on CloudBees, and I am trying to connect my spring app using spring Data.

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: 
Failed to authenticate to database [appDB], username = [MY_DB_USERNAME], password = [b**********1]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils.doGetDB(MongoDbUtils.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils.getDB(MongoDbUtils.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.getDb(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:118)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.getDb(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:107)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.ensureIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:213)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:146)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:120)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:257)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:120)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:49)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:268)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:137)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:141)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:83)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:147)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
... 46 more
```

My XML config for Spring Data:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="appDB"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
     <constructor-arg name="username" value="#{mongoUri.username}" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="#{new java.lang.String(mongoUri.password)}" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoUri" class="com.mongodb.MongoURI">
  <constructor-arg value="mongodb://MY_DB_USERNAME:MY_DB_PASS@paulo.mongohq.com:10048/xxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.mongodb.Mongo" id="mongo">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoUri" />
</bean>
```

When I test my URI mongodb://MY_DB_USERNAME:MY_DB_PASS@paulo.mongohq.com:10048/xxxxxxxxxxxxx using umongo, it connects correctly.

Maven dependencies:

```
spring data mongodb version: 1.3.1.RELEASE
mongodb driver version: 2.10.1
spring core version: 3.2.3.RELEASE
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the db username you are using an admin user?  If so you'll get a failed to authenticate message when authenticating against databases other than `admin`.

Comment: I don't think it's an admin user  (it's the basic free plan on cloudbees, i guess it's not possible to have an admin user with that plan), i will check if it's possible to have one. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing my DB name "appDB" by #{mongoUri.database} so the new Bean def for mongoTemplate is:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="#{mongoUri.database}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
</bean>
```

I don't understand why putting the DB name directly as String is wrong, but anyway for me it works with this XML config.